# Access a Global Variable in Main File with an Imported Javascript Function ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, javascript-import

I am using `Vue.js` but with simply `JS` files and not `vue` files and I am importing a component into my main `app.js` like so:

```
import autoPosts from './components/autoPosts.js';
```

It imports it just fine, but I am trying to access these globals. Before people destroy me for using global variables, can you just tell me if this is possible.

```
const apiRoot    = location.origin + '/wp-json/wp/v2/';
const acfApiRoot = location.origin + '/wp-json/acf/v3/';

import autoPosts from './components/autoPosts.js';
```

It doesn't read `apiRoot` or `acfApiRoot` within that component whether I include it before or after the variables.

The only way it works is if I declare the variables inside my component file `autoPosts.js`

Comment: You expect `autoPosts ` to read the variables `apiRoot` ?

Comment: yes, i am trying to get autoPosts to read the variables in the main file

Comment: Just because `app.js` is the main module doesn't mean that variables declared in it would be global.

Comment: i thought they were accessible but i was clearly wrong

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just because `app.js` is the main module doesn't mean that variables declared in it become global. But you should not use global variables anyway. Instead, create another module

```
// config.js
export const apiRoot    = location.origin + '/wp-json/wp/v2/';
export const acfApiRoot = location.origin + '/wp-json/acf/v3/';
```

that you can import where you need the constants:

```
// components/autoPosts.js
import { apiRoot, acfApiRoot } from '/config.js';
…
```

Comment: that's exactly what I should be doing. Had no idea this could be done. Need to brush up on newer javascript for sure

Comment: I would use the wildcard importer here (`import * as config from './config.js'`). Then you can reference your variables as `config.apiRoot` which is more easily understandable :)

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts Sure, which import style is considered simpler is a subjective choice.

Comment: @Bergi Do you know if the code in the imported file will be reevaluated every time it is imported? I'm searching for a way to only run basic functions (like 'isMobile') once and only reference them later. Or maybe the function is cached anyway and the performance increase isn't worth it...

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts Every module is instantiated and evaluated only once.

Answer (score 6):

just using

```
const apiRoot = 'whatever';
```

doesn't make it a global variable and is not accesible since it isn't exported.

To use a global variable, add it to window;

```
window.apiRoot = 'whatever';
```

and it will be accessible from any other classes with simple the variable name

```
console.log(apiRoot); // outputs 'whatever'
```

Comment: `window` is only available in browser scripts, but not in nodejs (or other server-side) applications.

Answer (score 3):

Can it not use window?

```
window.apiRoot = location.origin + '/wp-json/wp/v2/';
```

Comment: @NateBeers only when the variable is accessed after the module loaded, not during the execution of the `autoPosts` module